# Компиляция java кода по разным директориям с использованием javac

Tags: java, linux, консоль, java-8, javac

Нужно распределить все `*.java` файлы в папку `src/`, а все `*.class` в `bin/` или `release/` или `debug/`. Вопроса не было бы, если бы не тот факт, что пакетная организация в java завязана на файловой системе. Как принято правильно собирать небольшие проекты с помощью `javac`?
P.S. не советуйте мне пожалуйста `IDE`, я не хочу сотни раз запускать шайтан-машину ради HelloWorld)

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -d release -sourcepath src/ src/path/to/Main.java
```

или

```
javac -d release src/*.java
```

Но ещё лучше использовать Maven или Gradle.